# php/mysql select statement works manually but not by way of code

Tags: php, mysql

**SOLUTION: I was pointed at the wrong database thanks for the help.**

the count below returns 0 but when i run it manually there is a result.

by manually i mean copying the SQL that is echo'd by my code and pasting it into the mySQL command.

```
 <?
 $host="localhost"; // Host name 
            $username="userName"; // Mysql username 
            $password="userPW"; // Mysql password 
            $db_name="dbName"; // Database name 
            $tbl_name="userBase"; // Table name

            // Connect to server and select databse.
            $link=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
            mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

            // username and password sent from form 
            $user=$_POST['user']; 
            $pass=$_POST['pass'];


            // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
            $user = stripslashes($user);
            $pass = stripslashes($pass);
            $user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
            $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);

              $salt = substr($pass, 0, 1);
              $encrypted_pswd = crypt($pass, $salt);

            $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user=\"$user\" and pass=\"$encrypted_pswd\";";
            echo $sql."<br>";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);




            // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
            $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
            echo "count=".$count."<br>";
  ?>
```

Comment: the output is incorrect. should be count=1, but count=0. not sure why

Comment: not sure if this would work, but you could try to just put single quotes around user and password. so user='$user'

Comment: Maybe you have to remove the semicolon? `$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user=\"$user\" and pass=\"$encrypted_pswd\"";`

Comment: how sure are you that the crypt() return value is the same as the value you entered manually?

Comment: @stillstanding: "by manually i mean copying **the SQL that is echo'd by my code and pasting it** into the mySQL command"

Comment: time to debug your application.

Comment: BTW. doing `mysql_real_escape_string($pass);` is senseless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE user='%s' and pass='%s'", $tbl_name, $user, $encrypted_pswd);
```